# Android room not deleting cache properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a room dao interface where I store a list of schools. Here is the dao interface -

```
@Dao
interface SchoolDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertSchools(schoolList: List<SchoolModel>)

    @Query("SELECT * from schoolTable")
    suspend fun querySchoolList(): List<SchoolModel>?

    @Query("DELETE from schoolTable")
    suspend fun deleteSchoolList()
}
```

Here is the cache repository of mine -

```
override suspend fun storeSchool(schoolList: List<SchoolModel>) {
    schoolDao.insertSchools(schoolList)
}

override suspend fun deleteCache(): SchoolResult {
    schoolDao.deleteSchoolList()
    if (schoolDao.querySchoolList().isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return SchoolResult.EmptyNow
    }
    return SchoolResult.NotEmpty
}

override suspend fun getSchoolList(): SchoolResult {
    val result = schoolDao.querySchoolList()
    if (result != null && result.isNotEmpty()) {
        return SchoolResult.SchoolListContent(result)
    }
    return SchoolResult.Error(SchoolResult.ErrorType.SCHOOL_LIST_EMPTY)
}
```

The problem is when I make an API call, the call gives me 2 school times and I store it. 
Now I delete on the server database, one of the school item and the API gives me 1 school item which is totally fine.
Until now everything fine. Now when I turn off internet on phone, I expect to read from cache and cache gives me 2 items.
It seems the room cache is not updating.

Comment: you are not deleting data from room? how you are updating database?

Comment: Is it not possible to update rather than delete and insert?

Comment: maybe your equals for items stored in db is wrong? You have to be sure that db is able to recognize 'the same' items.

Comment: You have inserted two-row in database. Now until you delete the row, it will remain in database.

Comment: @AmitTiwary Can i not check if row exists by id, update it else insert it.

Comment: CMIIW i read the flow is like this Hit API -> Store Local DB -> delete data from API Server -> turn off data -> local DB data still 2? that's right?

Comment: if my flow is right, then the problem is you need hit the API again, because you update the data on server

Comment: Can you explain properly, what you want to achieve? You have deleted data from the server and you want that, that data should also get deleted from the local database.

Comment: As per my understanding, the flow is: Hit API -> Store Local DB -> delete data from API Server -> Hit API -> Store in Local DB -> turn off data -> local DB data still 2? that's right? The issue here is, is there a way to update the local db without deleting the whole table data and inserting the data again on second api hit for storing just one row.

Comment: @bhavya_karia yes is there a way?

Comment: As far as I know, clearing the table and then inserting the new data it the only way.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you have no problem in presented source code. I think the room here is working correctly. Most likely your problem is at an other level, for example, in the sequence of calling server api methods and db caching. 
Definitely here the problem is not in the room.